# NodeJS Consume Oauth Get API Call

Tags: node.js, api, oauth

I am trying to consume data from OAuth Enabled get API call in NodeJS. I need to pass two Online-Magazine-Subscription-Key and access token. I used '***request***' module to consume API call.

```
var accessToken = 'Bearer xxx...xxx';

request.get({
    url: URL,
    headers: { 'accept': 'application/json', 'Online-Magazine-Subscription-Key': 'x..xxx', 'Authorization': accessToken}
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

Its throwing error as "{ [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error] code: 'E CONNRESET' }". But the same API call is working fine in Rest Client and all other similar stuff.

Response is always undefined. Did I missed any thing in the above code?? Is there any other way to consume OAuth Enabled API Calls??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to proxy issue. But even after proxy is set it dint work in windows command prompt but works fine in Nodejs command prompt